# deploy war into NGINX

Tags: nginx

I need to host a java application on an NGINX server instead of on Tomcat7(current configuration), as the application is just a light-weight parser working as a data acquisition service for a sensor based device.
I know that deployment of war files is no-go on NGINX,so please suggest steps to port the application server from Tomcat7 to NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) [might be the option](http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers).
As far as I see it requires no code rewriting, just unpacking the `.war` file you already have.